# how to make live scoreboard in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

i am working on the simulation of coalition in agent society. Agents (turtles) form coalition dynamically and after some  times they left current coalition and joined other one. Hence, number of members (turtles) in the coalition vary on every tick. Some times because of no member in the coalition, coalition vanishes and some times two or more than two members (turtles) form the new coalition. I want to have live score board in simulation, which gives updated stats about the coalition and its members. For instance, how many coalition currently exist, what are the names of the coalition and how many members in each coalition. Could any one guide me which feature should i use to develop the live score board? Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `monitor` widget is the best option for current count of coalition membership (or `plot` if you want it over time). For more detailed information, have a look at using the `output` area with commands such as `output-show` to provide the information.